# Digest function in R query

Tags: r

I am using the digest function to mask some sensitive information in R.
Is it possible to retrieve the original data after masking?

Any insights would be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Priyanka

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input. We have no idea what your code does so it's hard to say for sure what's going on.

Comment: anonymize <- function(x, algo="crc32"){
  unq_hashes <- vapply(unique(x), function(object) digest(object, algo=algo), FUN.VALUE="", USE.NAMES=TRUE)
  unname(unq_hashes[x])
}

# choose columns to mask
cols_to_mask <-c("BENE_NUM","BENE_EQTB_NUM")

# backup original data
data_copy<-copy(my_data)

# anonymize
my_data[,(cols_to_mask):= lapply(.SD, anonymize),.SDcols=cols_to_mask,with=FALSE]

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible.  If you just need to hide the data from plain sight, you can use base 64 encoding.  E.g.:

```
library(base64enc)

x <- "sensitive data"
x64 <- base64enc::base64encode(charToRaw(x))
print(x64)
[1] "c2Vuc2l0aXZlIGRhdGE="

rawToChar(base64decode(x64))

[1] "sensitive data"
```

Otherwise, you can use encryption, which there are packages for.